# Which tools utilize for my SOA Project?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, soa, hypermedia

I've to develop an Image Server that should **provide REST API** supporting **Hypermedia**. (With basic functionalities like login, register, upload and download images)

I think to use *Glassfish* as a server to develop my project and *Java* as the programming language.

How can I develop the project? I think that a possible idea is to **create different Servlet** (that are my website pages) and insert links that connect different Servlets (example from login Servlet I can send information through post to itself and check the login data, if these are OK it creates a session and sends a GET request to the home Servlet).

It's correct to implement in this way? There are better ways to implement this service? (Maybe JSF)

I am asking here because I've the fear to miss completely the goal.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Spring projects. There's multiple Spring projects that seem very useful regarding what you indicate.

- **REST API supporting hypermedia** : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/
- **Security** (login, register) : https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/
- **Frontend** : https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-cli-and-js/

I think you should have multiple services ("Micro services") for your project.

For example :

- Authentification/User registration service
- Images upload/download service
- ...

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to run some simple example first of all.
BTW using Spring can be a limitation if I also want to support OAuth for third party applications. (Sorry if the answer can be expected, but I really don't know)